# change values in dataframe row based on condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataframe

```
    Region      2021    2022    2023
0   Europe      0.00    0.00    0.00
1   N.Amerca    0.50    0.50    0.50
2   N.Amerca    4.40    4.40    4.40
3   N.Amerca    0.00    8.00    8.00
4   Asia        0.00    0.00    1.75
5   Asia        0.00    0.00    0.00
6   Asia        0.00    0.00    2.00
7   N.Amerca    0.00    0.00    0.50
8   Eurpoe      6.00    6.00    6.00
9   Asia        7.50    7.50    7.50
10  Asia        3.75    3.75    3.75
11  Asia        3.50    3.50    3.50
12  Asia        3.80    3.80    3.80
13  Asia        0.00    0.00    0.00
14  Europe      6.52    6.52    6.52
```

Once a value in 2021 is found it should carry a 0 to the rest (2022 and 2023)
and if a value in 2022 is found -it should carry 0 to the rest. In other words, once value in found in columns 2021 and forth it should zero the rest on the right.

expected result would be:

```
    Region      2021    2022    2023
0   Europe      0.00    0.00    0.00
1   N.Amerca    0.50    0.00    0.00
2   N.Amerca    4.40    0.00    0.00
3   N.Amerca    0.00    8.00    0.00
4   Asia        0.00    0.00    1.75
5   Asia        0.00    0.00    0.00
6   Asia        0.00    0.00    2.00
7   N.Amerca    0.00    0.00    0.50
8   Eurpoe      6.00    0.00    0.00
9   Asia        7.50    0.00    0.00
10  Asia        3.75    0.00    0.00
11  Asia        3.50    0.00    0.00
12  Asia        3.80    0.00    0.00
13  Asia        0.00    0.00    0.00
14  Europe      6.52    0.00    0.00
```

I have tried to apply a lambda:

```
def foo(r):
   #if r['2021')>0: then 2020 and forth should be zero) 

df = df.apply(lambda x: foo(x), axis=1)
```

but the challange is that there are 2021 - to 2030 and the foo becomes a mess)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us try `duplicated`

```
df = df.mask(df.T.apply(pd.Series.duplicated).T,0)
Out[57]: 
      Region  2021  2022  2023
0     Europe  0.00   0.0  0.00
1   N.Amerca  0.50   0.0  0.00
2   N.Amerca  4.40   0.0  0.00
3   N.Amerca  0.00   8.0  0.00
4       Asia  0.00   0.0  1.75
5       Asia  0.00   0.0  0.00
6       Asia  0.00   0.0  2.00
7   N.Amerca  0.00   0.0  0.50
8     Eurpoe  6.00   0.0  0.00
9       Asia  7.50   0.0  0.00
10      Asia  3.75   0.0  0.00
11      Asia  3.50   0.0  0.00
12      Asia  3.80   0.0  0.00
13      Asia  0.00   0.0  0.00
14    Europe  6.52   0.0  0.00
```

Comment: @ProcolHarum I am not sure why ~ maybe just do not like the apply ~

Comment: I know that apply is a memory consumer but your answer is on spot

Comment: I am not sure -> havent tried, but maybe you can also explore df.shift on axis=1 and cumsum on axis=1 together to put in a condition too :)

Answer (score 1):

This is another way:

```
df2 = df.set_index('Region').diff(axis=1).reset_index()
df2['2021'] = df['2021']
```

or:

```
df.iloc[:,1:].where(df.iloc[:,1:].ne(0).cumsum(axis=1).eq(1),0)
```

Output:

```
    2021  2022  2023
0   0.00   0.0  0.00
1   0.50   0.0  0.00
2   4.40   0.0  0.00
3   0.00   8.0  0.00
4   0.00   0.0  1.75
5   0.00   0.0  0.00
6   0.00   0.0  2.00
7   0.00   0.0  0.50
8   6.00   0.0  0.00
9   7.50   0.0  0.00
10  3.75   0.0  0.00
11  3.50   0.0  0.00
12  3.80   0.0  0.00
13  0.00   0.0  0.00
14  6.52   0.0  0.00
```